# Windows phone 8 Image not refresh (ListBox with Binding)

Tags: binding, windows-phone-8

On MainPage ListBox

DataTemplate

```
<StackPanel>
 <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Height="160"></Image>
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Binding

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Refresh()");
ListBox.DataContext = db.Contacts.OrderBy(x => x.Order).ToList();
```

Image Binding

```
public ImageSource Image 
{ 
    get
    {
        string path = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "Image";
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("size: {0} time: {1}", fi.Length, fi.CreationTime);
            return new BitmapImage(path);
        }
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Images/empty.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);

        return image;
    }
```

From MainPage open SettingPage.

At SettingPage

- change DisplayName
- add and remove items from **db.Contacts**
- **ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "Image"** replaced with new image file;

Back to MainPage

- DisplayName - refresh
- new items - added
- removed items - deleted

**but image show OLD**

If restart app - show new image

**In diagnostic**

**Start MainPage**

*Refresh()*

*size: 96005 time: 11.01.2014 20:38:10*

**Open SettingPage - Change Image - Back to MainPage**

*Refresh()*

*size: 132404 time: 11.01.2014 21:05:00*

I see image has new size but in list box old image.

**Why image not refresh?**

Comment: You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: On Refresh/Bind collection full loaded from DB/DataContext. ListBox read property Image and get new value but show old. When call PropertyChanged? File from Image property changed in athother Page

Comment: Have you tried instead of the ImageSource binding to a string which contains the image url, or using the ListBox.ItemsSource property for setting the source of items?

Comment: Before i use string path to file with image. Image not refresh (app restart need). File path not change, change only file.

Answer (score 1):

[Found the solution here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/171dfe66-78b5-4340-bd78-244337f31287/bitmapimage-cache-issue?forum=winappswithcsharp)

```csharp
var img = new BitmapImage();
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
img.UriSource = new Uri(path);
```

Comment: This also worked for me loading bitmaps from an image source api.  When i loaded a "new" image from the api url (which redirects to provide the new real url), the OS was caching the original image and so the new one wasn't showing, by setting IgnoreImageCache, the new image shows. Thanks